# Laravel 5.5 Unit testing controller method

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5

I am trying to setup a simple unit test for one my controller method.

The goals is to test if the a view has an expected value.

```
/**
 * Does the homepage receive all companies when there is no licensekey provided.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testAllCompaniesOnHomepageWithoutLicensekey()
{
    $this->call('GET', '/');

    $allCompanies = Company::all();

    $this->assertViewHas('allCompanies', $allCompanies);
}
```

In my conosle I get the following error:

> Error: Call to undefined method
>   Tests\Unit\ExampleTest::assertViewHas()

I am not sure if this is no longer availbale in Laravel 5.5?

Anyone knows how I can test my goal?

Comment: @Troyer I don't see why I would use Dusk for this. I am not trying to do browsertests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you migrating from an older Laravel version? There have been changes to Laravel's browser testing in Laravel 5.4 https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade

In Laravel 5.5 you could try:

```
$response = $this->get('/');

$allCompanies = Company::all();
$response->assertViewHas('allCompanies', $allCompanies);
```

Comment: Ah I tried to debug `get_class_methods($this)` but you won it... (Y)

Comment: I am nog migrating from an older Laravel version.